# Unity Lazy resolve not working

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
}
```

and registration:

```
...
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>;
```

I'm trying to use **deferred resolution** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec33

```
public class Client
{
   public Client(Lazy<IMyInterface> myInterface)
   {
   }
}
```

But have an error: InvalidOperationException: The type Lazy`1 has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate unity container.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add more informative code? Because I successfully injected `Lazy` class on my local machine. Try to add parameterless constructor to your `MyClass`.

Answer (score -2):

It's strange, because I successfully injected it.

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    UserEntity GetUserEntity();
}

public sealed class Repository : IRepository
{
    public UserEntity GetUserEntity()
    {
        return new UserEntity
        {
            Name = "User's name"
        };
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    UserEntity GetUserEntity();
}

public sealed class Service : IService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IRepository> lazyRepository;

    public Service(Lazy<IRepository> lazyRepository)
    {
        this.lazyRepository = lazyRepository;
    }

    public UserEntity GetUserEntity()
    {
        var user = this.lazyRepository.Value.GetUserEntity();
        return user;
    }
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
            container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();

            IService resolvedService = container.Resolve<IService>();

            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {resolvedService.GetUserEntity().Name}");


            Console.WriteLine("\n\nTap to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```